# Uncaught TypeError: projects.map is not a function in Reactjs, was working before I made changes in MySQL

Tags: mysql, reactjs, array.prototype.map, primereact

My code was working before when my two tables in MySQL were both just "id".
To add more specificity and to be able to add a foreign key, I changed the ids in the two tables to:

bugtracker_table:
id --> project_id

ticket_table:
id --> ticket_id

Now all of the sudden I am getting the error: **Uncaught TypeError: projects.map is not a function** - on **line 25** in Dashboard.js (highlighted below), when before my app worked perfectly.

Dashboard.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { DataTable } from "primereact/datatable";
import { Column } from "primereact/column";
import { Button } from "primereact/button";
// import ButtonDemo from './ButtonDemo';
import { Chart } from "primereact/chart";
import { InputText } from "primereact/inputtext";
import { InputTextarea } from "primereact/inputtextarea";
import axios from "axios";
import { useHistory, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Dialog } from "primereact/dialog";
// import { Media } from "react-bootstrap/Media"
// import ProjectsTable from "./Tables/ProjectsTable";
// import TicketsPieChart from "./Tables/TicketsPieChart"
// import API from

//project table
//eslint-disable no-unused-vars
const TableDemo = () => {
    const [project_name, setProjectName] = useState("");
    const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
    const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);
    const history = useHistory();

Line 25    const projectsToShow = projects.map(project => {
            return {
                ...project,
                project_name: <Link to={`/projects/${project.project_id}`}>{project.project_name}</Link>,
            };
        });

    useEffect(() => {
        getProjects();
    }, []);

    const [displayResponsive, setDisplayResponsive] = useState(false);

    const getProjects = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:5002/bugtracker_table");
        setProjects(response.data);
    };

    const saveProject = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        await axios.post("http://localhost:5002/bugtracker_table", {
            project_name: project_name,
            description: description,
        });
        history.push("/");
    };

    const dialogFuncMap = {
        displayResponsive: setDisplayResponsive,
    };

    const onClick = (name) => {
        dialogFuncMap[`${name}`](true);
    };

    const onHide = (name) => {
        dialogFuncMap[`${name}`](false);
    };

    const renderFooter = (name) => {
        return (
            <div>
                {" "}
                <Button onClick={saveProject} type="submit" label="Submit" className="p-button-rounded p-button-success mr-2 mb-2 success" />
            </div>
        );
    };

    // const paginatorLeft = <Button type="button" icon="pi pi-refresh" className="p-button-text" />;
    // const paginatorRight = <Button type="button" icon="pi pi-cloud" className="p-button-text" />;

    return (
        <>
            <div className="grid table-demo">
                <div className="col-12">
                    <div className="card">
                        <h5>Projects</h5>
                        <div>
                            <Button className="p-button-rounded mr-2 mb-2 npbutton" label="New Ticket" onClick={() => onClick("displayResponsive")} />
                        </div>
                        <Dialog className="dialogModal" header="Create Ticket" visible={displayResponsive} onHide={() => onHide("displayResponsive")} breakpoints={{ "960px": "75vw" }} style={{ width: "35vw" }} footer={renderFooter("displayResponsive")}>
                            <form>
                                <h5>Project Name</h5>
                                <InputText value={project_name} onChange={(e) => setProjectName(e.target.value)} type="text" placeholder="Enter project name"></InputText>
                                <h5>Project Description</h5>
                                <InputTextarea value={description} onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)} type="text" placeholder="Enter project description" autoResize rows="4" cols="40" />
                            </form>
                        </Dialog>

                        {/* // <Link to="/ticketlist"  className="col-12"> */}
                        <div>
                            {/* // className="card"></Link> */}
                            <DataTable
                                // sortMode="single" sortField="representative.name"
                                editMode="row"
                                value={projectsToShow}
                                sortOrder={1}
                                scrollable
                                scrollHeight="400px"
                                responsiveLayout="scroll"
                                paginator
                                paginatorTemplate="CurrentPageReport FirstPageLink PrevPageLink PageLinks NextPageLink LastPageLink RowsPerPageDropdown"
                                currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {first} to {last} of {totalRecords}"
                                rows={5}
                                rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
                            >
                                {/* // paginatorLeft={paginatorLeft} paginatorRight={paginatorRight}> */}

                                <Column field="project_name" header="Project Name" style={{ minWidth: "200px" }}></Column>
                                <Column field="description" header="Description" style={{ minWidth: "350px" }}></Column>
                                <Column field="createdAt" header="Created On" style={{ minWidth: "150px" }}></Column>

                                {projects.map((project, index) => (
                                    <tr key={project.project_id}>
                                        <td>{index + 1}</td>
                                        <td>{project.description}</td>
                                        <td>{project.createdAt}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                ))}
                            </DataTable>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="grid p-fluid">
                    <div className="col-12 lg:col-6">
                        <div className="card flex flex-column align-items-center">
                            <h5>Tickets by Type</h5>
                            <Chart type="pie" focus={"type"} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="grid p-fluid">
                    <div className="col-12 lg:col-6">
                        <div className="card flex flex-column align-items-center">
                            <h5>Tickets by Priority</h5>
                            <Chart type="pie" focus={"priority"} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="grid p-fluid">
                    <div className="col-12 lg:col-6">
                        <div className="card flex flex-column align-items-center">
                            <h5>Tickets by Status</h5>
                            <Chart type="pie" focus={"status"} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};
export default React.memo(TableDemo);
```

I figured because I changed the id names in MySQL, I would need to adjust the id names in the backend as well **so I tried changing everywhere it said id before, to now project_id** but I think I did it incorrectly and believe this is where the error is coming from.

backend/controllers/products.js

```
import Project from "../models/productModel.js";
 
export const getAllProjects = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const projects = await Project.findAll();
        res.json(projects);
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({ message: error.message });
    }  
}
 
export const getProjectsById = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const project = await Project.findAll({
            where: {
                project_id: req.params.id
            }
        });
        res.json(project[0]);
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({ message: error.message });
    }  
}
 
export const createProject = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await Project.create(req.body);
        res.json({
            "message": "Project Created"
        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({ message: error.message });
    }  
}
 
export const updateProject = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await Project.update(req.body, {
            where: {
                project_id: req.params.id
            }
        });
        res.json({
            "message": "Project Updated"
        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({ message: error.message });
    }  
}
 
export const deleteProject = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await Project.destroy({
            where: {
                project_id: req.params.id
            }
        });
        res.json({
            "message": "Project Deleted"
        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({ message: error.message });
    }  
}
```

backend/routes/index.js

```
import express from "express";

import { getAllProjects, createProject, getProjectsById, updateProject, deleteProject } from "../controllers/Products.js";


const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", getAllProjects);
router.get("/:project_id", getProjectsById);
router.post("/", createProject);
router.patch("/:project_id", updateProject);
router.delete("/:project_id", deleteProject);
```

/backend/models/ProductModels.js

```
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";
import db from "../config/database.js";
 

    const { DataTypes } = Sequelize;
     
    const Project = db.define('bugtracker_table',{
        project_name:{
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        description:{
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        }, 
        createdAt:{
            type: DataTypes.DATE
        }
    },{
        freezeTableName: true
    });
     
    export default Project;
```

backend/database.js

```
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";
 
const db = new Sequelize('bugtracker_db', 'root', '', {
    host: "localhost",
    dialect: "mysql",
    port: 8889,
    username: "root",
    password: "root",
});
 
export default db;
```

Answer (score 1):

`Uncaught TypeError: projects.map is not a function` means that the variable assigned to `projects` is not an array, as the map function is only available on arrays.

If you take a look at the response you are getting from `http://localhost:5002/bugtracker_table` You will almost certainly see that this data is not a array.
In fact you do not have a route which corresponds to `/bugtracker_table`.

Try changing your routes file like below

```
router.get("/bugtracker_table", getAllProjects);
router.get("/:project_id", getProjectsById);
router.post("/bugtracker_table", createProject);
router.patch("/:project_id", updateProject);
router.delete("/:project_id", deleteProject);
```

So now your getAllProjects route matches up to what you are calling in React.

Comment: This answer looks smart.The data received as projects is not an array

Comment: @MUGABA Do you know how to change the data into an array? Like I stated above, It worked as is before I changed my mySQL id names. So I'm not sure why it'd work before if it wasn't an array then

Comment: @ttsssss I do not think there is anything wrong with your React code, as you said you have not change the name. However when you said you change the mySQL id names, you should only need to change it in once place in your `controllers/Products.js`. If you made changes in your React adding `bugtracker_table` then that is not right. If you can provide the response of http://localhost:5002/bugtracker_table then that will be helpful.

Comment: @DanielJ I added my /ProductModels.js if that helps add context.
I went to localhost:5002/bugtracker_table and got the message:
"{"message":"Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'"}" . 

Thank you for your help!

Comment: @DanielJ Does my controllers/Products.js file look correct? When it was working, the syntax was: id: req.params.id , instead of: project_id: req.params.id

Comment: @ttsssss Can I see your query that fetches data from the database I can start from there!

Comment: @MUGABA Yes! It is in Dashboard.js -  const getProjects = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:5002/bugtracker_table");
        setProjects(response.data);